# Ubuntu 20.04 rebooting and freezing

Tags: freeze, restart, 20.04

So I'm new to linux and my problem on hand is that Ubuntu keeps either freezing or rebooting and don't know where to start looking for what the exact problem is. I went to another forum and did the command they said for errors on system but don't know what to do with the info so i will give as much info as possible to help narrow it down. with my skill level this is all the info i could receive. Thank you for any help you can give.

```
Computer Specs:

description: Motherboard
       product: M11BB
       vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
       physical id: 0
       version: Rev X.0x
       serial: 131017391201484
       slot: To be filled by O.E.M.

description: System Memory
          physical id: 2b
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
          capabilities: ecc
          configuration: errordetection=multi-bit-ecc
        *-bank:0

description: CPU
          product: AMD A10-6700 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 3f
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: AMD A10-6700 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
          slot: FM2
          size: 1868MHz
          capacity: 3700MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb cpb hw_pstate ssbd vmmcall bmi1 arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=4

description: VGA compatible controller
                product: Oland PRO [Radeon R7 240/340]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
                resources: irq:36 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:fea00000-fea3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Audio device
                product: Oland/Hainan/Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7000 Series]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:35 memory:fea60000-fea63fff





dmesg came up with this error or code: 

[  388.008101] audit: type=1400 audit(1587789241.393:3018): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/mime.cache" pid=2021 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

[  388.008112] audit: type=1400 audit(1587789241.393:3019): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/globs2" pid=2021 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

[  388.008119] audit: type=1400 audit(1587789241.393:3020): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/magic" pid=2021 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

[  388.008128] audit: type=1400 audit(1587789241.393:3021): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/aliases" pid=2021 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

[  388.008134] audit: type=1400 audit(1587789241.393:3022): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/subclasses" pid=2021 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

[  388.008141] audit: type=1400 audit(1587789241.393:3023): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/icons" pid=2021 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

[  388.008147] audit: type=1400 audit(1587789241.393:3024): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/generic-icons" pid=2021 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

[  391.452025] audit: type=1400 audit(1587789244.837:3025): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/icons/Yaru/icon-theme.cache" pid=2021 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

[  391.452032] audit: type=1400 audit(1587789244.837:3026): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/icons/Yaru/8x8/emblems/" pid=2021 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

[  391.452478] audit: type=1400 audit(1587789244.837:3027): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/icons/Yaru/icon-theme.cache" pid=2021 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

Comment: I've also been running into freezes recently. Specs include a Ryzen 1600, NVidia 1060 with manually installed NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.82 drivers. Abnormal workload includes Docker, gnome-pomodoro, rescuetime, and a custom bash script/thread that runs `scrot` every two seconds/takes a screenshot. `systemctl` logs included:

`apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/mime/mime.cache" pid=2301 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0`, just like your apparmor stuff